# Kendo UI Grid frozen column issue with tooltips

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, frozen-columns, kendo-tooltip

I am with a ASP.NET web project that uses Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC Q2 2013 Grids.
My problem is when I lock a column, I lose the tooltip effect when hovering on a cell. I really dont know if it is a bug or something that I can change from configurations. Attached there are two screenshots, first one is tooltip being shown when the column is not locked. The second one is about the tooltip not appearing when the column is locked. Thanks for your help!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbwKW.png
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJRST.png
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I received feedback from Kendo experts. The problem was that locked colums have two tables definition and the tooltip was added only on one of them, so now I add to both tables and works OK!

Comment: How did you add it to the second table?